# Highly efficient way of reordering and rotating image simultaneously

Tags: c++, image, matlab, rotation, mex

For fast jpeg-loading I implemented a .mex-wrapper for turbojpeg to read (large) jpegs into MATLAB efficiently. The actual decoding takes only around 120 ms (not 5ms) for a 4000x3000px image. However, the pixel ordering is RGBRGBRGB... , while MATLAB requires a [W x H x 3] matrix, which in memory is a W*H*3 array, where the first WH entries correspond to red, the second WH entries to green, and the last WH entries to blue.
Additionally the image is mirrored around the axis from top left to bottom right.

The straightforward implementation of a rearrangement loop is the following:

```
// buffer contains mirrored and scrambled output of turbojpe
// outImg contains image matrix for use in MATLAB
// imgSize is an array containing {H,W,3}
for(int j=0; j<imgSize[1]; j++) {
    for(int i=0; i<imgSize[0]; i++) {
        curIdx = j*imgSize[0] + i;
        curBufIdx = (i*imgSize[1] + j)*3;
        outImg[curIdx] = buffer[curBufIdx++];
        outImg[curIdx + imgSize[0]*imgSize[1] ] = buffer[curBufIdx++];
        outImg[curIdx + 2*imgSize[0]*imgSize[1] ] = buffer[curBufIdx];    
    }
}
```

It works, but it takes around 120ms (not 20ms), about as long as the actual decoding. Any suggestions on how to make this code more efficient?

Due to a bug I updated the processing times.

Comment: On my 2GHz system, this loop takes 200ms+! What are you running it on?
I would, instead of sparse access to outImg, accumulate at least eight R, G and B values into temp variable and copy them at once. If that helps, I would increase the size of that temp storage.

Comment: If I read the code right, it implements `permute` and not `reshape`. Did you compare it with the performance of `permute`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Sorry, there was a serious, but awkward bug in my code, I updated the timings in my post. It's about 120ms for the loop on my machine (Xeon @ 3.6 Ghz). @ Daniel: It actually implements a combination of both, which, depending on the actual implementation, is slgihtly or significantly slower than the loop above.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**  99% of C libraries will store images row-major, meaning if you get a 3 x WH (a 2D array) from turbojpeg, you can just treat it as a 3 x W x H (the expected input above).  In this representation, pixels read across then down.  You need them to read down then across in MATLAB.  You also need to convert pixel order (RGBRGBRGB...) to planar order (RRRR....GGGGG....BBBBB...).  The solution is `permute(reshape(I,3,W,H),[3 2 1])`.

---

This is one of those situations where MATLAB's [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) command is probably going to be faster than anything you will code by hand on short notice (at least 50% faster than the loop shown).  I usually steer away from solutions with [`mexCallMATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html), but I think this may be an exception.  However, the input is a `mxArray`, which may be inconvenient.  Anyway, here's how to do a `permute(I,[3 2 1])`:

```
#include "mex.h"

int computePixelCtoPlanarMATLAB(mxArray*& imgPermuted, const mxArray* img)
{
    mxArray *permuteRHSArgs[2];
    // img must be row-major (across first), pixel order (RGBRGBRGB...)
    permuteRHSArgs[0] = const_cast<mxArray*>(img);
    permuteRHSArgs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,3,mxREAL);

    // output is col-major, planar order (rows x cols x 3)
    double *p = mxGetPr(permuteRHSArgs[1]);
    p[0] = 3;
    p[1] = 2;
    p[2] = 1;

    return mexCallMATLAB(1, &imgPermuted, 2, permuteRHSArgs, "permute");
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    // do some argument checking first (not shown)
    // ...

    computePixelCtoPlanarMATLAB(plhs[0], prhs[0]);
}
```

Or call `permute(I,[3 2 1])` yourself back in MATLAB.

What about the `reshape` to first go from 3xWH to 3xWxH?  Just tell the code that it's really 3xWxH! **`reshape` moves no data** -- it just tells MATLAB to treat a given data buffer as being a certain size.

Comment: My bad. Definitely a `permute` situation. +1

Comment: it is no problem to call permute in MATLAB directly, as I am processing the data in MATLAB anyways. However,a simple permute is not enough. Note that the image is also mirrored along the axis from top left to bottom right. One way to do it is: mex output is a 3xWH matrix `rawImg`, then do `img=permute(reshape(rawImg',4000,3000,3),[2,1,3]);` -> takes around 240ms per image.Faster: Output arbitrary, then: `for i=1:3, img(:,:,i)=reshape([rawImg(i:3:end)],4000,3000)';`  end,takes about 160ms. Both are slower than the loop posted originally. Or am I missing an idea on how to do it with permute?

Comment: @MrWayne 99% of C libraries will store images row-major, meaning if you get a 3 x WH (a 2D array) from turbojpeg, you can just treat it as a 3 x W x H (the expected input above).  In this representation, pixels read across then down.  You need them to read down then across in MATLAB.  You also need to convert pixel order (RGBRGBRGB...) to planar order (RRRR....GGGGG....BBBBB...).  The solution is `permute(reshape(I,3,W,H),[3 2 1])`.  You can modify the answer to assume the input is 3xWxH instead of 3xWH since there is no actual data moved in that change.

Comment: @chappjc Got it, thanks for solving the knot in my head. However, turns out that it is a lot slower compared to the original loop (the permutation itself takes around 300ms, almost 3x slower than the loop).

Comment: @MrWayne When I compare a `tic; permute(...); toc` to the C++ loop, it is much faster (about 50% as I noted).  How are you doing it and what kind of system (memory capacity)?  Perhaps MATLAB's not using multithreaded `permute` if there is one...

Comment: @chappjc I just tested on MATLAB 2012b and on 2015a. You are right, on 2015a it is using a multithreaded version of permute, putting load on 3 cores simultaneously, reducing the permute-runtime to 50ms and thus making it significantly faster than the loop. On 2012b the single-threaded version is running, which is slower. According to the MATLAB changelog performance was improved in 2013a.

Comment: Talking about parallelization: I implemented an OpenMP-parallelized version of the above loop, which was even faster than the `permute`-solution in 2015a. I'm happy with this version of the code now.

Comment: @MrWayne I just remembered this Q&A. Did you get an answer (even if you went a different route)? I hope I at least clarified a few concepts on this issue.

Comment: I actually did not pursue it any further and didn't get further answers - The parallelized version is fine for me.